# Error: Compiler version ^0.8.0 does not satisfy the r semver requirement

Tags: solidity, semantic-versioning, remix

I am new to solidity and I am running code on Remix.
It doesn't matter what version of compiler I specify, I keep on getting the same error.
Can someone help me out? What does "Compiler version ^0.8.0 does not satisfy the r semver requirement" exactly mean?

Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
```

pragma solidity ^ 0.8.0;

contract Storage {

```
struct People {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    string name;
}

mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;
People[] public people;

function addPerson(uint _personFavoriteNumber, string memory _personName ) public {
    people.push(People({favoriteNumber: _personFavoriteNumber, name: _personName}));
    nameToFavoriteNumber[_personName] = _personFavoriteNumber;
}
```

}
[image: This is my screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue a couple of times. In Remix, I added a ".0" to the compiler version like so:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4.0;
```

I ran into this in Virtual Studio code also but I just ignored it and everything worked fine. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It works in Remix as well, but I have worked on contracts that work without adding that ".0" at last, now even they show this error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.8.0;
```